# Quest: Upvote good and under appreciated questions and/or answers

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

There are far too many (IMHO) solid answers without so much as a single vote. Likewise, many a decent example of a question with too few upvotes. The voting system is there so we can show people what a good question looks like and what a great answer can be.

I propose a sitewide quest to get out there and find unsung heroes and give them some appropriate votes.

**Edit**: Perhaps we should say one underappreciated question per answer (thus, we only get a single nomination each)?

Comment: Totally! We definitely need a great increase in recognizing the good ones, particularly some of the answers to complex questions which can pass the radar.

Answer (score 5):

There are currently [47,701 answers with 0 votes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20votes%3A0) out of our 123,069 answers (38.75%).

[4,212 of those answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer%20score%3A0%20created%3A2019) were created in 2019.

**Please take into consideration** the quality of the answer before upvoting said answer. Low quality answers should be reported and a comment should be left asking the OP for clarification or to edit their answer and add any necessary details.

The links above should help any users in this quest!

Comment: This is a truly helpful list.